# Jsonify a list of custom objects

Tags: python, json, flask

I currently have the following:

```
class MainError:
    def __init__(self, code, message, errorsList):
        self.code = code
        self.message = message
        # List of Error objects
        self.errorsList = errorsList

    def serialize(self):  
        return {           
        'mainErrorCode': self.code, 
        'message': self.message,
        'errors': self.errorsList         
        }


class Error:    
    def __init__(self, field, message):
        self.field = field
        self.message = message
```

So I would like to return `JSON` in the format:

```
{
  "mainErrorCode" : 1024,
  "message" : "Validation Failed",
  "errors" : [
    {
      "field" : "first_name",
      "message" : "First name cannot have fancy characters"
    },
    {
      "field" : "password",
      "message" : "Password cannot be blank"
    }
  ]
}
```

Currently I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: <errors.Error instance at 0x329b908> is not JSON serializable
```

I am using `Flask's` `Jsonify`.

```
return jsonify(errors=mainError.serialize())
```

I'm guessing that the `list` is causing the issue. Could someone please help me with the right way of going about this?

PS: There might be some other glaring errors in my approach (I'm quite new to Python =/)

**Updated Solution**

```
def serialize(self):  
     return {           
     'mainErrorCode': self.code, 
     'message': self.message,
     'errors': [error.serialize() for error in self.errorsList] 
     }

class Error:    
    def __init__(self, field, message):
        self.field = field
        self.message = message

    def serialize(self): 
        return {           
        'field': self.field, 
        'message': self.message
        }
```

Comment: I assume it's not the indentation (`serialize` is module level)? Also, what's the relation (or heirarchy) between `Error` and `MainError` and how is it enforced?

Comment: @ReutSharabani I am not receiving any indentation errors. Is there something wrong with the way I've written it?

Comment: it's not an error, but serialize should probably part of `MainError`. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Ohhh oops.. yeah sorry it is! I didn't indent it correctly when I posted the question. I will fix it.

Comment: Now what about the relation between the classes `Error` and `MainError`?

Comment: I have written them in the same `module`. The `MainError` object will contain a list (`errorsList`) of `Error` objects.

Comment: I think all that's left is making `Error` serializable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error suggests, you have a list of `Error` objects that are not serializable. So make them serializable:

```
class Error:    

    def __init__(self, field, message):
        self.field = field
        self.message = message

    def serialize(self):  
        return {           
            'field': self.field, 
            'message': self.message
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Reut. I have included my new solution based on what you mentioned. Is the `for loop` the correct way of calling the `serialize` function?